# How to make multilevel boxes

Tags: boxes

I've been trying to make a multilevel boxes for my project, but I can't get them to look right. Here is how they look now

[image]

And here is the code I used to make them:

```
\boxed{
    \!\begin{aligned}
    &\textbf{FULL}

    &The patient had mutation in \emph{HFE}.

        \boxed{
            \!\begin{aligned}
            &\textbf{GENERAL}

            &We found links between \emph{ABO}, \emph{BRAC1} and \emph{TP53}.

            \boxed{
                \!\begin{aligned}
                &{\textbf{STRICT}

                &We detected \emph{BRAC1} and \emph{BRAC2} in the patient.}
                \end{aligned}
            }
            \end{aligned}
        }
    \end{aligned}
}
```

I want the biggest box to enclose all smaller boxes and so on and so forth.
Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: surely the posted code didn't make the output shown? `aligned` is a math construct so for example would set `The patient had mutation in` in math italic with no spaces.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `\parbox`es of increasing size (or decreasing, depending on how you look at it).

```
\documentclass{article}  
\begin{document}
\fbox{\parbox{4.5in}{\parindent=1em\relax\noindent\textbf
{FULL}

The patient had mutation in \emph{HFE}.

  \fbox{\parbox{4in}{\parindent=1em\relax\noindent\textbf
  {GENERAL}

  We found links between \emph{ABO}, \emph{BRAC1} and \emph{TP53}.

    \fbox{\parbox{3.5in}{\parindent=1em\relax\noindent\textbf
    {STRICT}

    We detected \emph{BRAC1} and \emph{BRAC2} in the patient.
    }}
%
  }}
%
}}
\end{document}
```

[image]